# Changing what a property is serialized as

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer

I think i already know the answer to this, but i cannot find anything that states it definitively, hence my question - i want to make sure i am not missing a trick.

Using the DataContractSerializer or the XmlSerializer, is there any way to change what a pulic property is serialized as? I have a property that is an `Enum`, and i would like it to be serialized as an `int`, so that its value is sent across the wire instead of a text representation of its value. Is it possible to do this using attributes, or will i have to write my own serializer?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that's what are you looking for: [XmlEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlenum%28VS.71%29.aspx). You can specify what should be saved during serialization for each enum value.